# Flutter- Make the app show the previously fetched data when device is offline

Tags: android, json, api, flutter

I'm new to Flutter and need a bit of help. I've built a random joke generator app that reads data from the API and displays a new joke every time a button is pressed. **I want to make the app show the previously fetched data when device is offline**. I tried searching online but found nothing that does it using Flutter.

```
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List data;
  Future<Jokes> post;
  String url="https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/random_joke";
  var response;
  Future<Jokes> getData() async {

     response =
        await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       return Jokes.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
     } else {
       throw Exception('Failed to load post');
     }



  }

   changeApi()
  {
    setState(() {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return Jokes.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load post');
      }
    });
  }

@override

void initState()
{
  super.initState();
  this.getData();
}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(

      key: key,
      backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
      body: new Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new FutureBuilder<Jokes>(
              future:
                  getData(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  //checks if the response returns valid data
                  return Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[

                        new GestureDetector(

                          child: new Text(
                            snapshot.data.setup ,
                            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Rock Salt"),
                          ),
                          onLongPress: ()
                          {
                            Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: snapshot.data.setup, ));
                            key.currentState.showSnackBar(
                                new SnackBar(content: new Text("Copied to Clipboard"),));
                          },
                        ),
                        /
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),

                        new GestureDetector(

                          child: new Text(
                            " - ${snapshot.data.punchline}",
                            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Roboto"),
                          ),

                          onLongPress: ()
                          {

                            Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: snapshot.data.punchline));
                            key.currentState.showSnackBar(
                                new SnackBar(content: new Text("Copied to Clipboard"),));
                          },

                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  //checks if the response throws an error
                  return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                }
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 25.0,
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: changeApi,
                color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                child: Text("Press for a new joke", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,)),
            )


          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Jokes {
  final String setup;
  final String punchline;

  Jokes({this.setup, this.punchline});

  factory Jokes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Jokes(setup: json['setup'], punchline: json['punchline']);
  }
}
```

[Api](https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/random_joke)

Here's my full code: [code](https://github.com/suvans98/webarch_task/blob/master/lib/main.dart)

Comment: Include your code etc to the question as a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This'll get you a quicker response. Also follow the How To Ask guide before posting a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask If your question does not fit into the How To Ask guideline, try beginner programming forums & groups which will help better than SO. If you've got precise technical problems with your code then post it on SO. If you don't follow SO questions guideline your question might be downvoted or closed with no gain or response. You can edit your question to improve it, though.

Comment: You can use the single source of truth pattern, see this article:
https://blog.usejournal.com/android-studio-mvvm-single-source-of-truth-pattern-2e0bea70b747

Answer (score 0):

There are some videos about caching, here's the one from [flutter team](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bud7XR8crWw), and one from tensor programming [channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iu3a0kf6-Fw).

You can use [connectivity](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/connectivity) plugin to check whether the device is offline.
If device is offline, show data from [shared_preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) or [sqflite](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite), if it's online, fetch new data (and of course update your cache).